# Is there a method to record video chat app (Google Duo, Skype, Tango, etc.) straight to the phone?

Tags: applications, video-recording, call-recording, video-calling

I am trying to record all the video calls with my parents. However, every video chat app that I know does not support a recording option. I have tried 3rd-party screen recording apps but they did not work. It seems the screen recording app clashes with the video chat app for the microphone. So, all I get is a recorded video chat without sound, or a good recorded video chat but the person who I am calling cannot hear my voice.

I searched everywhere and even contacted Google support but with no luck.

Would it be possible, or would I have to wait for the video chat app to start supporting recording?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [OP's 3rd revision of the question](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/164320/3),

> As of 01-20-2023, if you are using Samsung devices, you can record the whole conversation. Just click built-in screen recorder in the quick panel. The size of the file will be big, but it is worth it. I am not sure about other Android devices.

Answer (score -1):

For privacy reasons, voice from phone calls is not recordable.   Not only is this limited by Google but also by your device and carrier.   You can use an external recorder.

> Recording Limitations on Android
> Google has never been particularly fond of call-recording apps for Android, at least not those from third parties. With Android 9, the company added limitations that prevented many apps from recording your phone conversations. The apps seemed to work, but when you would play the recording, you’d hear only silence or just your end of the conversation.
>
> With Android 10, Google cracked down even further on these types of apps by blocking call recording via the microphone. In response, many app developers started tapping into Android’s Accessibility Service to record phone calls. But Google then updated its developer policy in April 2022 to state that it would not allow apps in the Play Store to use the accessibility service for call recording. That policy went into effect on May 11, 2022.
>
> The company has even gone so far as to label call recording a type of spyware.

From [PC Mag](https://au.pcmag.com/android-apps/92090/how-to-record-calls-on-your-android-phone)

Comment: To my knowledge, this ***is a restriction in Android created by Google***.  Many devices include hardware that supports recording phone calls, but Google's Android OS still does not allow it.  Carriers have nothing to do with any of this... they have no idea if anyone is recording *(except when they are aiding in the recording themselves)*, nor can they prevent anyone from recording; they are just passing bits back and forth using well-documented protocols.  Note that recording phone calls is 100% legal in many jurisdictions, and in most other jurisdictions simply requires consent.